# .caf file length differ ,even duration is same

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have .wav sound file for duration 5sec with Audio channel 2 and total bit rate is 1411200. I am converting this file to .caf format via command on terminal.
After file conversion it give following info audio duration is again same ( 5 sec), but audio channel is 1 and total bit rate with 705600.

Now this .caf file is keeps inside NSBundle. I need to recording same duration audio file and compare it with pre-recorded file. But when ever i NSlog both(recorded and pre-recorded) sound with NSData length ,it gives large byte difference(approx. just double).

I do not understand why this happen ,even both sound is .caf file with same duration.
Please help me. Thanks in adv.

Thanks 
Sudesh

Answer (score 0):

It depends on following factors of [Core Audio Format Specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CAFSpec/CAF_spec/CAF_spec.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001862-CH210-TPXREF101)

```
 struct CAFAudioFormat {

 Float64 mSampleRate;

 UInt32  mFormatID;

 UInt32  mFormatFlags;

 UInt32  mBytesPerPacket;

 UInt32  mFramesPerPacket;

 UInt32  mChannelsPerFrame;

 UInt32  mBitsPerChannel;

 };
```

Also check [this](http://new2objectivec.blogspot.in/2011/09/use-ima4-compression-to-reduce-caf-file.html) which also states depending on above factor caf file length changes